# Get file input value as binary data

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I access the binary representation with JavaScript from a file uploaded with a file input?:

```
<input type="file" name="file">
```

I can access the details of the uploaded file successfully with:

```
$('[name="image"]').get(0).files[0].name
// "2013-10-19 15.10.59.jpg"

$('[name="image"]').get(0).files[0].size
// 774016

$('[name="image"]').get(0).files[0].type
// "image/jpeg"
```

But not the real representation.

I found [this](http://igstan.ro/posts/2009-01-11-ajax-file-upload-with-pure-javascript.html) tutorial that makes use of:

```
document.getElementById("photo").files[0].getAsBinary()
```

However, that method doesn't exists in my browser (Chrome Canary 34.0.1772.0 on OS X 10.9).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File.getAsBinary

> Non-standard
> This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

It suggests:

> Note: This method is obsolete; you should use the FileReader method readAsBinaryString() or readAsArrayBuffer() instead.

However, [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) has several other read functions that might be more appropriate, like `readAsDataURL()` which lets you immediately use the file in web context (e.g as `<img>` src attribute), see the [method listing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader#methods) for all options.

```
// Retrieve the first (and only, unless using the `multiple` attribute) File from the FileList object
const f = document.getElementById("photo").files[0]; 
    
if (f) {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(evt) { 
    const metadata = `name: ${f.name}, type: ${f.type}, size: ${f.size}, contents:`;
    const contents = evt.target.result;
    console.log(metadata, contents);
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(f);
}
```

Comment: `readAsBinaryString()` is deprecated as per the 12 July 2012 Working Draft from the W3C.

Comment: This answer is so confusing. It says you should use `readAsBinaryString()` and then at the end it doesn't use it at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use the readAsBinaryString method of the FileReader API